# Save XML in Outlook public folder

Tags: outlook, public, file-sharing

May this is not the right place to ask, but prior to an Outlook plugin development I would like to get clarification.

As I understand, public Outlook folders used to share information among several accounts.

Can I save XML files, or that sort of files, in the public folder, or only Outlook objects such as Tasks, Notes?

Comment: Are you trying to save a document accessible to an end user, or some hidden data to be used for some storage purposes?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, Exactly. Any ideas?

Comment: Do which one ? The former or the  latter?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, To them both: I plan to store some XML files that contains data related to Outlook, and then to retrieve the data and show it to the end user when he prompts an Outlook plugin.